# HTML Background video for mobile size?

Tags: html, video

So I have a problem with my website. When ever I start it as a desktop version of it it opens the video as it suppose to: https://edgaraxe.net/teamhusky/

Here is the code for the video:

```
<div class="background-wrap">
   <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
      <source src="video/husky.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Video not supported
   </video>
</div>
```

However if I open it for mobile version I get a black screen.

[image]

Is here any way to make the mobile version open the video? Because I looked for a solution and people say its not supported to play videos on phone.
So instead is there a way to open a image instead for the mobile version?

Comment: Opinion: White text on a white background is a horrible choice.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a parameter `poster` to your `video` tag like this:

```
<video .... poster="PATH_TO_IMAGE" autoplay="false">
    ....
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<video />` tag has `poster` attribute which will be displayed on devices which support `video` element, but does not support autoplay.

```
<video poster="URL_TO_IMAGE" id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
    <source src="video/husky.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Video not supported
  </video>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple video formats in order to run the video on multiple browsers (including mobile ones). So, try adding a .webm video:

```
<div class="background-wrap">
   <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
      <source src="video/husky.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="video/husky.webm" type="video/webm">
      Video not supported
   </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you have to convert the video using a properly codec or format. Check [this website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) that contains a table with browsers compatibilities.